# 2º Parte del error J-son en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error404

Este error me impide publicar post, me impide entrar a ver mis productos, y me da error 404 en los productos que voy a ver.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos posibles causas a tu error:

- No tienes activada la opción de url amigables( pretty URLs ).
- Puede que sea un plugin el que está ocasionando el error.

En el primer caso, debes de ir a `Ajustes->Enlaces Permanentes` y activarlos.

En el segundo caso, una solución es desactivar todos los plugins y ver que funciona corréctamente. Con eso ya nos aseguramos que sea un plugin. Después, ve activando uno a uno cada plugin y a la misma vez vas probando a entrar a ver tus productos. Cuando se te vuelva a producir el error, el último plugin activado es el culpable.

Una vez detectado el plugin contacta con el autor para que solucione tus problemas.